# How can I have visualized embeddings on tensorboard? Not MNIST data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to create visualized graph on Tensorboard embeddings, I'm using csv data, not MNIST data, the data in csv is like follows:

```
    0.266782506,"1,0"
    0.361942522,"0,1"
    0.862076491,"0,1"
```

The data in first column like 0.366782506 is sample input_data x, and "0,1" is the one-hot label y. while 0

I tried to take reference on how to creat visualized graph by embedding projector on Tensorboard, but I found examples only by using MNIST data, so I'm looking for help if anyone can give a guidance on how to create a visualized embedding graph on Tensorboard.
I can have SCALAR, GRAPH and HISTOGRAM visulized on Tensorboard with my code as following:

```
    # coding=utf-8
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy
    import os
    import csv
    import shutil
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

    #Reading data from csv:
    filename = open('D:\Program Files (x86)\logistic\sample_1.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(filename)
    t_X, t_Y,c = [],[],[]
    a,b=0,0
    for i in reader:
        t_X.append(i[0])
        a= int(i[1][0])
        b= int(i[1][2])
        c= list([a,b])
        t_Y.extend([c])
    t_X = numpy.asarray(t_X)
    t_Y = numpy.asarray(t_Y)
    t_XT = numpy.transpose([t_X])
    filename.close()

    # Parameters
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 5
    batch_size = 50
    display_step = 1
    n_samples = t_X.shape[0]

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    with tf.name_scope('Input'):
        with tf.name_scope('x_input'):
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1],name='x_input')
        with tf.name_scope('y_input'):
            y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2],name='y_input')

    # Weight
    with tf.name_scope('layer1'):
        with tf.name_scope('weight'):
            W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 2],dtype=tf.float32),name='weight')
        with tf.name_scope('bias'):
            b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2], dtype=tf.float32),name='bias')

    # model
    with tf.name_scope('Model'):
        with tf.name_scope('pred'):
            pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b, name='pred')
        with tf.name_scope('cost'):
            cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1),name='cost')
            tf.summary.scalar('cost',cost)
            tf.summary.histogram('cost',cost)
        with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


    # Calculate accuracy
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy_count'):
        with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
                tf.summary.scalar('accuracy',accuracy)
                tf.summary.histogram('accuracy', accuracy)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    sess.run(init)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('D:\Tensorlogs\logs',sess.graph)


    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(n_samples / batch_size)

        i = 0
        for anc in range(total_batch):
            m,n = [],[]
            m = t_X[i:i+batch_size]
            n = t_Y[i:i+batch_size]
            m = numpy.asarray(m)
            n = numpy.asarray(n)
            m = numpy.transpose([m])
            summary, predr, o, c = sess.run([merged, pred, optimizer, cost],feed_dict={x: m, y: n})
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
            i = i + batch_size
        writer.add_summary(summary, epoch+1)

    if (epoch + 1) % display_step == 0:
        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", avg_cost,"W=",wr,"b=",br,"accuracy_s=",accuracy_s.eval(feed_dict={x: t_XT, y: t_Y}))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Thank you ver much!

Comment: Did you take a look at this tutorial? https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz

Comment: Yes, I've looked it, yet still confused about how to use codes like tf.train.saver, projector in the right way. The example given  by the tutorial is using MNIST data, but in my case it is csv data.